# Cannot create vagrant box from digital ocean with packer?

Tags: vagrant, digital-ocean, packer

I'm using port-processor of packer to create vagrant box from digital ocean image, but i get this error:

```
==> digitalocean (vagrant): Creating Vagrant box for 'digitalocean' 

provider
Build 'digitalocean' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Poorly formatted artifact ID: 12740136

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> digitalocean: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Poorly formatted artifact ID: 12740136

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

this is my post-processor code

```
"post-processors": [
          [{
              "type": "vagrant",
              "keep_input_artifact": true
          },
          {
              "type": "atlas",
              "artifact": "{{user `atlas_username`}}/{{user `atlas_name`}}",
              "artifact_type": "vagrant.box",
              "metadata": {
                  "provider": "virtualbox",
                  "version": "0.0.1"
              }
        }]
```

I'm build it remote with packer 0.8.1dev on atlas.hashicorp.com. how can i fix it?

Comment: Your post-processor failed because the build failed. Fix the build.

Comment: I'm currently getting this same error.  Without the post-processors block, the build is successful.  With it, this error occurs.  It's not the rest of the build.